# Execute Client DLL from an ASP page

Tags: asp.net

What is the best way to call a DLL on a client PC from an ASP page?

I have asp.net page that need to call function in dll installed on client machine because this function access resources related to client. how I can do this?

Thanks alot

Comment: a little bit more information would be great =)

Answer (score 0):

Let the client system download ActiveX control or Java applet that you embed into the web page, and let that control or applet do the rest. THis is possible only given that the user grants permissions to do this, otherwise it would be breaking into the user's computer.

Comment: but ActiveX Control has browser limitation is there onther way i can do that?

Comment: I am really not sure but did you try this approach? I think for signed ActiveX controls you can set permissions to let them load external DLL. But of course, this is user-dependent, i.e. the user must allow this operation in browser security settings. 

As said, any other way is hacking and will be suspicious or illegal activity.

Comment: can i use WCF ,i mean can i install service on client machine and call this service from we page java script function?

Comment: JavaScript is way too restricted in browsers. Applet or ActiveX is your only way at the moment (Silverlight or Flash won't help).